# Orchard CMS - How to redirect URL request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, routes, orchardcms

I've created an Orchard Website that consists of many mini-websites made operable via theme selection relating and triggered by the current [unique] URL all from the same DB. 
It works as I'd hoped, but I wish to improve the Autoroute paths of my pages.

Currently I'm using:

```
{Content.Fields.PageOrderPart.SitesTaxonomy.Terms:0}/{Content.Slug}
```

Which results in:

*www.site1.com/sitealpha/gallery*

*www.site2.com/sitebeta/gallery*

What I would like is:

*www.site1.com/gallery*

*www.site2.com/gallery*

However, I still need to be able to differentiate pages with the same name [...hence why the Autoroute path above was created in the first place] - or I will obviously get permalink duplication errors.

Can anyone think of an ingenious way to sort this or is there some Orchard feature I may've missed, perhaps url rewrites or possibly an existing MVC method?

Many thanks for your input, PP

---

**Further thoughts** (hopefully this doesn’t influence any other member's sugestions):

*Rewrite rules*: Probably aren't dynamic enough for the amount of content I have [still increasing] - and I could see any alterations to existing permalinks being a real nightmare.
Besides, for an unkown reason - I and some other Orchard users - can't seem to get a rewrite action to work?

*Routes:* Honestly, I haven't played with these properly - I can see that capturing and dissecting a URL to stipulate the area / controller / action should be easy enough - but I'm not sure how to go about redirecting to a particular Orchard page?

*FilterProvider, IActionFilter*: I tested this scenario [which could become quite complicated code wise] and I'm not sure the performance is acceptable -- my dev system seems to really suffer with any code in the 'OnActionExecuting' method.

---

**Update:** I've investigated the IActionFilter scenario and it appears my initial performance worries were unfounded [i.e. a fresh install didn't behave any slower with some URL restructuring code on the 'OnActionExecuting' method].

My last hurdle is to discover why IIS Rewrite rules aren't working with Orchard:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226580/orchard-cms-iis-rewrite-rules-do-not-work-for-rewrite-action-types

Answer (score 0):

It could be that multi tenancy would be the feature you are after. You can have one code, one db but they are all completely separate sites. So separate admin areas etc.

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-orchard-site

Comment: Thanks Hazza, multi-tenancy would be great - but I avoided it due to your last point [separate admin control] - I needed to access all my content from one admin, which I can do via this method; 'is it the best method, I'm not sure, but it works' ;)  I've added some further thoughts to my post.

Comment: Would it be possible to use Routes? As *for whatever reason* - I can't get IIS Rewrite [of rewrite type] rules to behave correctly with Orchard, although they work in normal MVC apps - so therefore, it renders my IActionFilter useless? Though I have no idea how I would intercept / change / resend URL requests via Routes for my Pages - as in, with everything being dynamic - how can I update the routes table with an area/action for a module that doesn’t exist? Thanks PP